# Sveltekit load function apparently not being called

Tags: javascript, routes, svelte, sveltekit, svelte-component

I'm new to Svelte and Sveltekit and I'm working on a very basic app which has a page such as:

`src/routes/categories/[slug]/+page.svelte`

In another page I've got a link to the page previously mentioned. When a click on the link it successfully redirects me to `[slug]/+page.svelte` and I can see the URL well formed:
`http://localhost:5173/categories/test-6`

Now, I'm trying to get the `[slug]` part of the URL when the page is loaded. I was going through the docs and read about the `load` function so I implemented:

```
<script context="module">

    /** @type {import('./$types').PageLoad} */
    export function load({params}) {
        console.log(params.slug);
        const slug = params.slug;
        return {
            slug
        };
    }
</script>

<script>
    let slug = undefined;
</script>


<h1>{slug}</h1>
wassap
```

but when I access the page I see only:

```
undefined
wassap
```

I don't even see the log statement I added to `load`.

What am I missing?

NOTEL I'm aware I could use perhaps `onMount` and `$page` and access the params in some other way, but I'd like to do it using `load`, seems so much cleaner to me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your load function should no longer be in a `context="module"` block, but rather in a seperate file called `+page.js`:

```js
export function load({params}) {
  console.log(params.slug);
  const slug = params.slug;
  return {
    slug
  };
}
```

the result of this is placed in an object `data` so in `+page.svelte` you would have now:

```html
<script>
  export let data;
</script>

<h1>{data.slug}</h1>
```

Comment: Also the `data` can now be strongly typed using `/** @type {import('./$types').PageData} */` (or the TS equivalent if pre-processing).

Comment: this worked, thanks. Does this `+page.js` should be at the same level of my `+page.svelte`? what is the purpose of `+page.js`? I mean, what other things should belong to that file?

Comment: It should be at the same level yes, some other things that currently belong in it are prerender, ssr, and other flags.  In the future this might become more and splitting it up offers posibilities there (and keeps the page component a bit cleaner) you can check the docs here https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#page-page-js